# Not receiving time_sync_fc_time_utc message from DJI ROS SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm trying to correlate time from the DJI A3 controller on an M600 to the GPS time from another device, and to do that, I'm trying to use the `time_sync_fc_time_utc` and `time_sync_gps_utc` ROS messages. I am able to successfully call the `/dji_sdk/set_hardsyc` service, but I never receive either of those two messages. I'm up to date for firmware, OSDK and ROS OSDK. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use `/dji_sdk/set_hardsyc` service, you have to set some hardware synchronization mechanism. Please refer [to this page](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/guides/component-guide-hardware-sync.html) to see what this is all about.

About `time_sync_fc_time_utc` and `time_sync_gps_utc` topics, DJI official answer is that those topics can only be used with M210 (see [this thread](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/issues/301) on their github). Why is that ? Well, I would really love to know ! But they never provide any information , though this question has been asked several times.

Theoretically, I don't even see why we would need hardware synchronization just to read the data coming from the GPS.